# Child of Constraint layout in scrollview - fill available space or wrap content

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

## Requirements

**content smaller than scrollview:** child should fill up all available space

**Content bigger than scrollview:** child should wrap it's content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:text="ipsum dolor amet flank fatback jerky tenderloin sausage bacon spare ribs rump pork."
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In this case, TextView2 should fill up all available space.
However, if TextView2 contains a lot of text, it should wrap it's contents.

I can achieve only one of these requirements, but not both at the same time.

## Current scenario

TextView2 will spread to fill the space, but if there is more text, it won't be scrollable.

If I add `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` to TextView2, It will be scrollable, but it will not take up all available space if the content does not exceed the scrollviews size.

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish both these things, at the same time?

Comment: I can give you a programmatic solution if you are interested. I think that a straight XML solution, as you might be suspecting, is not possible. Ping me back if you want a way to do this in a little code.

Comment: We adjusted our layout so this isn't necessary anymore, thanks!